# Get current user's profile with rails and react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm finally taking the leap and learning React with Rails. Currently at the basics and need some help showcasing the current logged in users profile link. I understand the process of doing this just need help with execution.

Before, a link to the currentUser's profile with erb was like this

```
<li><%= link_to 'Profile', current_user %></li>
```

I'm now rendering my 'Navbar' component like so

```
<%= react_component 'Navbar' %>
```

and this is the actual component:

```
var Navbar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
      return {
      };
  },
  getDefaultProps() {
      return {
          siteTitle: "React Test"  
      };
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="navi">
        <div className="logo">
          <h1>{this.props.siteTitle}</h1>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav">
          <li className="item">
            <a href="#" className="hvr-float-shadow">Profile</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

How do I set the current user id in the component state.

Comment: react_component take props. Please refer to react-rails documentation, and react documentation itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use props to pass in data:

```
<%= react_component('Navbar', current_user: current_user)  %>
```

Assuming your profile path is something like:

```
localhost:3000/profile/:id
```

Then your react would be:

```
var Navbar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      currentUser: this.props.current_user
    };
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href={"localhost:3000/profile/"+ this.state.currentUser.id}>Profile</a>
        <li>
      <ul>
    );
  }
},
```